# convert input button into a href

Tags: php, html, echo, href

How do I create an a href link of this:

```
echo "<td><input type='button' class='btn btn-link text-dark' value='{$val_str}' onclick='redirect(\"{$value}\")'></td>";
```

Because I don't think google will index a button input type?

I tried this:

```
echo "<td><a href='redirect(\"{$value}\")'>{$val_str}</a></td>";
```

But that doesn't work

Comment: BTW this is the website page, https://internetspeedtest.info/en/world, but I'm not sure if i am allowed to post it here

Comment: What is the value held within `$value`? The cited website has buttons as here but without the `redirect` function as far as I can see. But I do see hyperlinks of the form `https://internetspeedtest.info/nl/redirect(%22Belgium%22)` ~

Comment: Based upon observations at quoted website it looks like the hyperlinks could simply be `<a href='/nl/land/{$value}'>{$val_str}</a>` - if there is no particular need for the Javascript of course

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Yes, that worked.

But I also added this `function redirect(country) {
        location.href = 'country/' + country;
    }` 

So I don't know what I still need to hard-code the /country/ text

Comment: The favourite approach is to register an external event listener for these types of links rather than embedding `inline` event handlers within your HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

Without "hard-coding" the links as I think your comment was suggesting and to use Javascript you could use an approach similar to this.

```js
const redirect=function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    
    let baseurl='https://internetspeedtest.info/en';
    let url=[ baseurl, 'country', this.textContent.replace(/\ /gi,'_') ].join('/');
    
    location.href=url;
};


document.querySelectorAll('a.country').forEach(a=>{
  // display a simple title
  a.title='View stats for: '+a.textContent;
  
  // assign the event handler
  a.addEventListener('click',redirect)
})
```

```html
<a href='#' class='country'>India</a>
<a href='#' class='country'>Belgium</a>
<a href='#' class='country'>United States</a>
<a href='#' class='country'>Norway</a>
```